# How To Format Timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have `col1` in `myTable` which is `varchar`, and I have to insert here timestamp eg:- `09-MAY-11 10.23.12.0000 AM`.

Now please tell me:

- How to insert into myTable with taking sysdate in above format...
- How to retrieve data from col1 in tha same timestamp format..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

INSERT:

```
insert into myTable (col1) VALUES (to_char(systimestamp, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh.mi.ss.ff4 AM') );
```

SELECT:

```
select to_timestamp(col1, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh.mi.ss.ff4 AM')  from myTable ;
```

But it is much better to store the data directly as a timestamp.
Then you can compare the values ​​or modify them directly.

```
create table myTable1( col1 timestamp default systimestamp);
```

Comment: select to_timestamp(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh.mi.ss.ff4 AM') from dual 
This give me '11-MAY-11 12.00.00 AM' 
but i want '11-MAY-11 01.45.00 PM' (i mean time is getting truncated to 12:00:00 but i want actual time)

Comment: `select to_char(systimestamp, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh.mi.ss.ff4 AM') from dual;` And if you don't want and if you don't want the fractional seconds then: `select to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh.mi.ss AM') from dual;`